# How to initiate a logfile and change handler.suffix in a TimedRotatingFileHandler

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I have a script that monitors a platforms chat, and logs it to a file. Here is the code to setup my logger:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers as handlers
import time
from datetime import datetime

chatlogger = logging.getLogger("chatlog")
chatlogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logHandler = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler('chatlog_', when='midnight', interval =1, encoding='utf-8')
logHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logHandler.suffix="%Y%m%d.log"
chatlogger.addHandler(logHandler)
logHandler.doRollover() #this line is needed if when=midnight, otherwise it does not crate the proper file
```

This works, the chatlog_.yyyymmddd.log gets created and it rolls over when it should. However, there are two small issues I'd like to address/address differently.

The first is that the very first log file the script creates does not have the suffix; it is just 'chatlog_' and nothing else. I added in the doRollover() to correct this, is a different or better way to handle initiating the logfile? The script will be run 24/7(*or as close to that as possible), being restarted with the machine.

The second issue is more of an aesthetic thing. The logHandler.suffix() adds in a '.' between the filename and suffix. Is there something I can do to so stop that from happening?